# OpenSliceDDS across a network

Tags: data-distribution-service

I am completely new to the DDS world. I understand basic concepts like publish and subscribe, and the stuff that can be gained from the documentation.  I am attempting to use OpenSlice DDS, and am able to get through the tutorial without much difficulty.  However, I want to get two different computers on the same network to talk to each other, which seems like a relatively simple task, but i can find no documentation on it.

For example, the message chat room tutorial... how would i get the message board running on one machine, and the chatter on another machine?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are on a LAN, the tutorial should just work out of the box between different machines. Just run one application on one machine and the other application on another machine. The two will discover each other automatically.

Comment: Yup; the issue i was originally running into turned out to be a firewall issue; i just had to turn iptables off on one of the machines;

Answer (score 0):

Found it! http://opensplice.org/pipermail/developer/2009-July/000094.html.

To summarize from the link:

1. Setup your environment on node 1 by running the release file in the OSPL_HOME directory (release.bat)
2. start the opensplice daemon on node 1 (ospl start)
3. run the messageboard application on node 1
4. Setup your environment on node 1 by running the release file in the OSPL_HOME directory (release.bat)
5. start the opensplice daemon on node 2 (ospl start)
6. run the chatter application on node 2